# Requires installation of untrusted packages in elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, updates

[image]

I am using latest elementary OS. I have some updates in my laptop but when i hit update button it says **Requires installation of untrusted packages**. How can I solve?

Comment: please let me know my answer is useful or not...if solved please accept it as answer.

Comment: does your problem solved ?

Comment: yes! it is now solved.

Comment: please acept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**:

To solve this install `y-ppa-manager`.To install open terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Now run `y-ppa-manager` from terminal.

When main y-ppa-manager window openend,click on <kbd>Advanced</kbd>

From the advaced list--> click on **Try to import all missing GPG keys** then click OK.

**Option 2**:

Open *Software and Updates*, change `download from` to  : **Main Server** ,then try again.

**Option 3**:

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

<sub>Reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)</sub>